# Simple Linq question: How to create query with logic operators

Tags: linq-to-sql, .net-3.5

Just began to develop using LINQ, and still can't understand some simple things.
So,
`LinqTable.SingleOrDefault(t=>(t.Field1=="value1"))` is equal to SQL `"SELECT * FROM LinqTable WHERE Field1="value1" LIMIT 1"`

How to create (using Linq) the query like `"SELECT * FROM LinqTable WHERE Field1="value1" AND Field2="value2" LIMIT` 1?

Comment: Just a note - `SingleOrDefault` will throw an exception if there is more than one matching record. `FirstOrDefault` will not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SingleOrDefault(t=>(t.Field1=="value1" && t.Field2=="value2"))

Comment: I tried it before and It didn't work, I swear! But now I tried again and it works.Thank you

Comment: +1, you don't have to use the extra (). @Setrul: to understand LINQ better, do a Google search for "LINQ 101"

Answer (score 3):

```
LinqTable.Where(row => row.Field1 == "value1" && row.Field2 == "value2").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: +1 for FirstOrDefault(). The question, as stated, doesn't indicate that the values would find a unique result.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you'd want to use `Where` to do this:

```
var result = LinqTable.Where(t => t.Field1 == "value1" && t.Field2 == "value2").SingleOrDefault();
```

You can do this directly in the SingleOrDefault line as well:

```
var result = LinqTable.SingleOrDefault(t => t.Field1 == "value1" && t.Field2 == "value2");
```

Comment: Don't use Where but use the overload of SingleOrDefault that accepts a predicate.

Comment: Both options work, fine, and actually will create the same SQL in EF and L2S.  Personally, I find using Where more descriptive, in this instance, given the goals of the OP.